# TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, programacion-asincrona

Estoy consumiendo una api desde reactjs, al momento de intentar mostrar los datos en una tabla me retorna el siguiente mensaje: de **this.state.data is not a function:**

[image: error]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De La información que encontré fue que en el data dentro del steate algunos los tenían como: data:"", y solo era pasarlo a: data:[] pero yo ya lo tengo así y aun asi me sigue marcando el error.

Este es el código:

```js
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faEdit,faTrashAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

//import { faEdit,faTrashAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
//import { Modal, ModalBody, ModalFooter, ModalHeader } from 'reactstrap';

const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/venta";

class Report extends Component {

   
        state = {  
            data:[]
            }
  
    peticionGet=()=>{
        axios.get(url).then(response => {
            this.setState({data: response.data});
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.peticionGet();
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
            <br />
            <center><button className="btn btn-success">Agregar Nuevo</button></center>
            <br /><br /> 
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Apellido</th>
                        <th>Telefono</th>
                        <th>Correo</th>
                        <th>Acciones</th>               
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.state.data.map(ventas=>{
                        return(
                            <tr>
                                <td>{ventas.ventas_id}</td>
                                <td>{ventas.nombre}</td>
                                <td>{ventas.apellido}</td>
                                <td>{ventas.telefono}</td>
                                <td>{ventas.correo}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button className="btn btn-primary"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit}/></button>
                                        {"   "} 
                                    <button className="btn btn-danger"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt}/></button>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>    
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Report;
```

Alguna idea o sugerencia seria de gran ayuda y muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, ¿y estás seguro de que la respuesta de Axios (el response.data) es un array? ¿Puedes loguearla para ver el contenido?